# use of null environment is defunct error in RInside

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm dealing with RInside on Ubuntu. I have installed R, Rcpp and RInside. I built my C++ code successfully, but when I run my program I get the next error: "use of null environment is defunct" on the first line `RInside R(argc, argv)`

What is more wondering, on one machine it works well, but when I try to run the same code on another machine I get an error.

In Internet I have found the next phrase: "from version 2.4.0, the use of NULL as an environment is defunct". So it seems like there are not compatible versions of R, Rcpp and RInside. It works well with R v2.15.1 and RInside v0.2.11 but do not work with R v3.0.3 Rcpp v0.11 RInside v0.2.11. Is there any list of compatible versions of this libraries? or maybe there are some other reasons for this error.

Answer (score 0):

CRAN versions should be current at each point in time.

Use the RInside version that corresponds to the matching Rcpp version from the same time -- ie both current.

Also go into `examples/standard` directory for RInside and say 'make' which should create over a dozen working examples. Here I just build the first:

```
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard$ make  rinside_sample0 
g++-4.8 -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include \
-I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -g -O3 -Wall -pipe \
-Wno-unused -pedantic -Wall    rinside_sample0.cpp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib \
-lR  -lblas -llapack  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib \
-lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -o rinside_sample0
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard$ ./rinside_sample0 
Hello, world!
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard$
```